# shell script for 24 hrs data files upload to ftp ; unable to identify the issue

Tags: shell, unix, ftp

```
file_list=$( find . -type f -name * -mtime -1 )ftp -n << EOF
open ftpip

user uname pwd

cd directory

prompt

hash

bin

mput $file_list

bye

EOF
```

unable to upload with the above script... and through invalid command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the problem with quoting the asterisk, and the fact that your "ftp" statement needs to start on a new line, I suspect your $file_list variable could get far too long to be handled well. I have made you a little script that uses "tar" to collect up the files you want into a single archive named after today's date. Then you can FTP that instead of 8 million files ;-)

Here you go:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Make dated tar file of everything from last 24 hrs, filename like "Backup2013-12-14.tgz"
#
FILENAME=`date +"Backup%Y-%m-%d.tgz"`
find . -type f -mtime -1 | tar -cvz -T - -f "$FILENAME"

ftp -n << EOF
open somehost
user joe bloggs
prompt
hash
bin
mput "$FILENAME"
bye
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to put `*` in quotes so it doesn't immediately expand or remove 
`-name *` altogeather since it's default option.

Comment: You're not really piping anything into `ftp`. And not sure you should be using it to begin with.

Comment: Here i am getting the find results into file_list and mput for piping these files to ftp... Hope you advice

Comment: Is there some particular reason your'e using ftp? e.g. Look into http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/06/perform-ssh-and-scp-without-entering-password-on-openssh/ Then just pipe the file into scp and copy it to remote host in one line. And put the entire line in a crontab if you haven't already, if this is something you want done daily.

Comment: :I would like to upload files that are modified from past 24 hrs... For which i would like to create a shell script and use this in cron tab

Comment: You can do it using ftp, though not sure about your syntax, but really ftp was never meant to be used programmatically like this. scp and a few other programs do it easily.